# How to adjust sensitivity of y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have these y-axis values that I  want to plot each on a x-tick using a bar plot to show the difference (the first below value for the x-tick 1, the second value for x-tick 2 and the third for the x-tick 3)

```
0.9999893294851471
0.9999997569910387
1.0
```

for now I am trying to get helped by `ylim`, but in vain:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3]
y=[0.9999893294851471,0.9999997569910387,1.0]
plt.bar(x,y,align='center') 
plt.plot(x,y, 'r--', label='Default')  
plt.xlabel("tick") 
plt.ylabel("values") 
plt.ylim(0.9999800, 0.9999999) 
plt.show()
```

Any clues?

Comment: could you define the x and y variables with your data so we can run the code? matplotlib should automatically adjust the y limit based on your data. if you could post an image of the plot you are getting and why is wrong it will also be helpful to understand your question

Comment: `x=[1,2,3], y=[0.9999893294851471,0.9999997569910387,1.0]`

Comment: could you please edit your question, include the code to import libraries and the definition of variables? as is now, we have to include the missing imports, copy paste the variables from the comment and copy paste the code from the question.  Your code your be runnable by just copy/pasting it

Comment: Providing a schematic of the expected graph would also be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `plt.yticks(y)`  to your code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3]
y=[0.9999893294851471,0.9999997569910387,1.0]
plt.bar(x,y,align='center') 
plt.plot(x,y, 'r--', label='Default')  
plt.xlabel("tick") 
plt.ylabel("values") 
plt.ylim(0.9999800, 1.0) 
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

However, since the values are very vey close, matplotlib adds an offset to the scale, to the ticks refer to this offset.
That's why you see a value of -0.067, since the scale is 1e-5  with an offset of 9.9999e-1

I'm not sure how you can disable this automatic offset and force matplotlib to show the actual values.

If someone knows how to disable this automatic offset it will be very interesting if an answer handling this could be posted.

[image]

Comment: seems to me the 0.976 and 1.00 values are too close, could you show their difference in Y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this  way:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [0.9999893294851471, 0.9999997569910387, 1.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, align='center')
ax.plot(x, y, 'r--', label='Default')
ax.set_xlabel("tick")
ax.set_ylabel("values")
ax.set_ylim(0.9999800, 1.0)
ax.set_yticks(y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For given x and y values, I used Matplotlib to make a bar plot and overlay a dashed line plot, showing them as bars and a line on the same plot. Arrays in NumPy are used for effective data mangement.

Comment: Could you post a picture of how the plot looks like with your code?

Comment: I just added . this is for your requirement . when your value is changed your output will be changed.